# AIFFault object does not have method 'new' - problem when posting packing slip

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, cil, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, aif

I have a problem posting a packing slip. Posting is stopped with this message: **AIFFault object does not have method 'new'**. I made some changes to my method that already existed in the 'SalesPackingSlipJournalPost' class. In my opinion, these changes are very safe, nothing that would have a big impact on posting. When I have the **'Execute business operations in CIL'** checkbox unchecked, everything works fine, but when I check it, there is a problem when posting.

I did probably everything, compile class, forward compilation of this class, full CIL, deletion of AUC files and usage data. I also restarted AOS but no change. What else can I do? If I have checked the 'Execute business operations in CIL' checkbox, I can't debug in this class and I can't find where's the problem.

Comment: Could you [edit] the questions and add the changes made to the packing slip posting? Did you take a look at https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/312106/aiffault-object-does-not-have-method-new? To "reset" CIL, also take a look at [deleting the XppIL folder](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/no-audience/2014/06/22/how-to-force-complete-cil-recreation-in-ms-dynamics-ax-2012/). And finally, to debug CIL, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/debugging-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012#batch-jobs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.